# how to prevent to run a code in the same second

Tags: c#

I have this code to generate unique code for each record:

```
private readonly object _binaryLock = new object();

public string Generate2()
{
    lock (_binaryLock)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        return $"{date.Year}{date.Month:00}{date.Day}{date.Hour}{date.Minute}{date.Second:00}".Substring(2);
    }
}
```

but now I want to be sure that each record will get a truly unique value. If two clients request a new value at the same time, I think both of them get the same value.

How can I avoid it or how can I check it?

My project is using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Add ms to your Code ?

Comment: return `Guid` not date or `Guid`+date

Comment: I have limit rules . I dont want to use Guid beacause its too long

Comment: In this case  it helps clients to know when the record was add

Comment: @Rafalon If I add `Millisecond` it becomes too long

Comment: @GiladGreen I don't want to use `Guid` I want to use this code beacuse I need a template

Comment: So remove year and add milliseconds or remove year and append some random number.

Comment: "In this case it helps clients to know when the record was add" - separate the two concerns. Use a GUID or a sequence number for uniqueness, and a separate field to store the creation time. Note that your current format is ambiguous anyway, as an hour/minute of "111" could mean "01:11" or "11:01". (You'd have been better using date formatting: `{date:yyyyMMddHHmmss}`.) What *exactly* are your constraints on the size of the identifier?

Comment: @JonSkeet my constraint is that clients should can Remember it or easily pronounce it .

Comment: I wouldn't expect humans to be able to remember a date/time down to the second to start with. Where does that constraint come from? Please edit your question to give much more context here - if we don't know your requirements or the reasons for them, it's much harder to help you.

Comment: This sounds like a XY-Problem to me...

Comment: @JonSkeet clients dont have to remember but it is based on a template and its pretty nice for them

Comment: That's a *really* vague requirement, I'm afraid. I don't think you're going to be able to get any help until you clarify the question. I agree with CShark about this being an X-Y problem.

Comment: the result is like :`170903100201` it means year2017,month :09 and others .

Comment: That's not the result of the code you've got at the moment which wouldn't pad the minute/second values with zeroes. (I'd strongly recommend against the use of Substring here as well - "17" isn't *nearly* as clear as "2017".)

Comment: @FullStack What do you do with the generated ID? Where do you store this data? When it is a database, can't you just use the AUTO INCREMENT value from the database instead? What is the code/project around that code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a table in database and save last created ID in it, then simply check equality of created ID and last created ID ( In database ).

Answer (score 0):

Holding a execution for second is not good modal with the scaling approach and will become bottleneck in future. Rather than this we can use the Ticks of DateTime

```
                DateTime.Now.Ticks
```

which is I think will be shorted and easily converted back into the datetime

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that using `DateTime.Now.Ticks` has a resolution of about 16ms on windows systems (depending on the actual OS). When you have two calls/threads in that 16ms time frame they will get the same value for `DateTime.Now.Ticks`.